# Cannot use member variable inside onEnable()

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a public class and within that class I have:

```
Msg msg = new Msg();
```

But I can't access `msg` from the `public void` methods of the class.

It works if I:

- Put `Msg msg = new Msg();` before `msg` every time I use it.
- Do `new Msg().log("")` instead.

It doesn't work if I try:

```
private static Msg msg = new Msg();
```

```
public static Msg msg = new Msg();
```

The error I am getting in console is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: enji/lep/Msg at enji.lep.chat.Chat.<init>(Chat.java:16)
```

Relevant code follows:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

/* Created by enji */

public class Chat extends JavaPlugin {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");
    Msg msg = new Msg();

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        msg.log("Talliban bajs i simskolans sovrum!!!!"); // This causes the error
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        log.info("Plugin off");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
getLogger().info("Talliban bajs i simskolans sovrum!!!!");
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not thread safe.
Weird [data race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) is possible if `Chat` object is created (and its member `msg` is respectively initialized) in one thread but the method `Chat#onEnable()` (which uses that `msg` member) is invoked from another thread.

To account for above, one can for example declare `msg` `final`:

```
private final Msg msg = new Msg();
```

Creation of new instance "in place" is safe, too (that's why it worked when you tested it):

```
new Msg().log("");
```

As far as I can see, above would also make having `msg` member in `Chat` redundant so that you could simply remove it.

Another option could be to convert `Msg.log` method to static and invoke it via class instead of instance:

1. Declare `log` method in `Msg` class `static`.
2. Invoke with `Msg.log("")` instead of `msg.log("")`.
3. Get rid of `Msg msg = new Msg();` since it's not needed anymore.

See an example:

```
class Msg {
    public static void log(String msg) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`log` and `msg` are both objects, there isn't a `log` method on the `Msg` class so `msg.log` will not work.
You can call public methods of `Msg` from the `msg` object, but not objects you created.